If $N$ is a submodule of $M$, isn't it trivial that every sequence $f:N\otimes E\to M\otimes E$ is injective for each $R$-module $E$?
Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity.  If $N$ is a submodule of $M$ with $rmR=r^2mR$ for each $r\in R,m\in M$, then every sequence $0\to N\otimes E\to M\otimes E$ is exact for each $R$-module $E$.
My proof:
In trying to prove this, I am supposed to first show that the map $f:N\otimes E\to M\otimes E, f(m\otimes e)=m\otimes e$ is injective.  For this part, I think that this is obvious since $N$ is a submodule of $M$, there exists a natural injection $\iota:N\to M$.  This induces the injectivity of $$f:N\otimes E\to M\otimes E$$  for each $R$-module $E$.
I am remaining with the struggle of proving exactness.
My question is whether I am right on the first part. Also how to handle the last part?

I am confused by the condition "$rmR = r^2 mR$ for all $r\in R, m \in M$". Since $R$ is commutative, shouldn't the left and right scalar multiplications coincide?

Please look at the notion of a flat module and examples of non-flat modules, explained in detail in several questions on this site. This should clear up your confusion. The root cause is that $\otimes$ for elements is ambiguous here.

There is a lot of confusion here, because the exactness of the sequence exactly means that $N\otimes E\to M\otimes E$ is injective. But you did in fact not prove this injectivity as your argument is flawed: just because $N\to M$ is injective does not imply that $N\otimes E\to M\otimes E$ is injective, unless $E$ is flat. I assume something special is going on under your hypotheses.

Your first part is not Ok. Look at $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $M=\mathbb{Z}$, $N=2\mathbb{Z}$ and $E=\mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z}$. Denote by $f:N\to M$ the inclusion $f(2n)=2n$, for any $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and consider:
$f\otimes id : N\otimes_R E \to M\otimes_R E$, then for any $n\in N$ and $e\in E$: $$(f\otimes id)(2n\otimes e)=f(2n)\otimes e = 2n\otimes e = n\otimes 2e = 0.$$
Thus $f\otimes id = 0$. Note that since $N\simeq M\simeq R$, you have $N\otimes_R E \simeq E \simeq M\otimes_R E$.
